# Lebesgue measure and continuity of a function.

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A,B$ be Lebesgue-measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m$ be Lebesgue measure and $m(A)<\infty.$

Prove that $f(x):=m((A+x)\cap B)$ is continuous.

$\Big( A+x=\{ a+x | a\in A\}\Big)$.

I can use the following **Fact**.

**Fact**

If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m(E)<\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} m((E+x)-E)=0.$

I tried but couldn't prove.

Set $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}.$
I'll prove $|f(x)-f(a)|\to 0 \quad (x\to a)$.

If I could prove $|f(x)-f(a)|<m((A+x-a)-A)$, let $x\to a$ and I could prove that $f(x)$ is continuous, using the **Fact**.

But I cannot prove
$|f(x)-f(a)|<m((A+x-a)-A)$.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\e\varepsilon$There might be a smarter way to go about this, but here is a naive approach. Let $\e>0$. Then there exists $V$ open with $V\supset A$ and $m(V\setminus A)<\e/4$. Note that this implies that $m(V)<\infty$. Now
$$
m((V+x)\cap B)-m((A+x)\cap B)=m((V\setminus A)+x)\cap B)\leq m(V\setminus A). 
$$
Then
\begin{align}
|f(y)-f(x)|
&\leq \e/2+m((V+y)\cap B)-m((V+x)\cap B).
\end{align}
Now since $V$ is open, we may write it as a disjoint union of open intervals, $V=\displaystyle\bigcup_n(a_n,b_n)$. The finite measure of $V$ gives $\sum_n(b_m-a_n)<\infty$. We have $$m(E)-m(F)=m(E\setminus F)-m(F\setminus E).$$ Then, for $x<y$,
\begin{align}
m((a_n,b_n)+y)\cap B)-m((a_n,b_n)+x)\cap B)&\leq m((a_n+x,a_n+y))+m((b_n+x,b_n+y))\\[0.3cm]
&\leq2(y-x). 
\end{align}
So, we choose $n_0$ such that $\sum_{n>n_0}(b_n-a_n)<\e/4$. Then if $|y-x|<\e/(2n_0)$,
\begin{align}
|f(y)-f(x)|&\leq \frac\e2+\sum_nm((a_n,b_n)+x)\cap B)\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\frac\e2+\frac\e4+\sum_{n>n_0}m((a_n,b_n)+x)\cap B)\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\frac\e2+\frac\e4+\frac{2n_0\e|y-x|}{2n_0}=\e.
\end{align}

Comment: When $E=[0,1]$, why $E+x-E=[\min\{0,x-1\}, x+1]$ for $x\geqq 0$ ? If $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $E+x=E+\frac{1}{2}=\{ a+\frac{1}{2} | a\in [0,1] \}.$ For $a+\frac{1}{2} \in E+\frac{1}{2}, 0\leqq a \leqq 1$ so $\frac{1}{2} \leqq a+\frac{1}{2} \leqq \frac{3}{2}$. Thus $E+\frac{1}{2}=[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}]$. $E+\frac{1}{2}-E=[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}]-[0,1]=(1, \frac{3}{2}].$ This is not equal to $[\min\{0,x-1\}, x+1]=[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}]$.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly: you use $+$ to denote addition of numbers, and $-$ to denote set difference? How do you denote subtraction?

Comment: In my mathematics book, $A-B$ means$\{ x | x\in A, x\notin B\} $.

Comment: Not your fault then, but still a horrible notation. In such book, you could write $(E-x)-E$ and the two minus symbols have a different meaning. And it's worse because it is common, when you are in a vector space to consider $A-B=\{a-b:\ a\in A,\ b\in B\}$. This is the usual meaning of the symbols.